# Once you understand motors, what's the next step?

Tags: motor, mechanism

I've gone through tutorials on how to build circuits and control dc, stepper, and servo motors.  I may not understand everything about them internally, but i have a good basic foundation.

Now i'm at a loss for where to go from here.  I'm more interested in learning how to make mechanical devices with them than just the electronics behind the devices.  While i know that they go hand in hand, i want to learn more about the mechanical aspects of using motors.

I have in mind several ultimate goal projects that i want to work toward, like home automation, model rc vehicles, autonomous robots, etc...  But i'm sure that there is more to mechanics that i need to learn before i can jump into a project like that.  ***He who will learn to fly one day must first learn to stand and walk.***

Are there hobbyist mechanical starter kits or starter projects to learn how to make effective use of electric motors?  I don't necessarily need a specific product endorsement, but rather a general idea of what important concepts to learn and materials / projects to help me learn them.

My apologies if this question is too broad.  I can refine it if deemed necessary.

Comment: I would probably head towards sensors, such as ultrasonic, range, and things of that nature. Then try to take the two and make them work togeather

Comment: "dc, stepper, and servo motors". These can be one type, a Stepper is a DC Motor, and with a feedback it will become a Servo (with a controller ofcourse). Please take a look at my answer at [this question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/what-are-the-different-types-of-electric-motors), specifically at the servo-motors chapter.

Comment: One thing to look at is how to mount the motor and how to connect it to a load.  What sort of tools do you have access to?  Milling machine?  Lathe?

Comment: @GuySirton:  just basic power tools.  No lathe or mill.

Comment: @GuySirton:  connecting it to loads sounds interesting.  How do i get started with that?

Comment: study calculations of strength and velocidade.em gears, levers and straps.
Attaching the motor rotates.

Comment: **Life Questions** are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, and they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation and are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat].

Comment: @MarkBooth:  Agreed.  I had a feeling my question was a bit too open ended.  No worries! :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding Paul, we look forward to seeing your questions when you start to have specific problems we can help you with.

Answer (score 2):

so now you have a good foundation of motors and the similar electro-mechanical actuators.
You have to learn or you have to build up a concepts of all kinds of mechanical parts needed to do a project on a mechanical robotics.
see there are so many things nto thr domain of robotics but first you have to go step by step.
as you have a good knowledge about the motors then go through there ratings and emf and all the ratings stuffs and after that try to know which motors are used for which purposes.
see for robotics the purpose of using the components should be known to do a project in robotics domain.so after gathering the practical knowledge you may tend to the different parts onto them.Try to design a system especially a mechanical system that may be a simple one **(like a robotic mechanical arm)** and then try to implement some **gear related and pully related mechanical system** that will do a specific job for you.or you can interface these kinds of motors like a system of **steering system of a car etc** or you may try something innovative generator system by using motors you have or you can interface it to a analog circuit to make a low cost mechanical system for a specific requirement.you cann try a different one like you can make an **autonomous system using a microcontroller or microprocessor system** and interface it with some sensors and after sensing the environment you can control the actuators to get your requirement done!
hope the suggestions may help you.